# InvalidCastException when casting from base class to inherited class?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, casting

```
public abstract class ContentManagedEntity
{
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }

    public bool Active;

    public int DisplayOrder;
}

public class StoreCategory : ContentManagedEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class XMLStoreCategory : StoreCategory, IXMLDataEntity
{
    public bool Dirty = false;
}

void main() {
    var storecategory = new StoreCategory { Name = "Discount Stores" };
    var xmlstorecategory = (XMLStoreCategory) storecategory; // Throws InvalidCastException
}
```

Is there a reason it throws an InvalidCastException at runtime on the last line?

(Bah, as I wrote this, the answer popped into my head, clear as day. Posting it up for posterity, and just to make sure I have it right.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All `XMLStoreCategory` objects are `StoreCategory`s, but not all `StoreCategory`s are `XMLStoreCategory`s. In this case you're creating a `StoreCategory` and trying to cast it into something it's not.

Comment: Yup, figured it out as I was posting the question. Feeling pretty dumb right now. Oh well, at least if someone else contracts a temporary case of "teh st00pid", they can refer to this. :)

Answer (score 4):

You're asking this:

```
class Animal { }
class Cat : Animal { }
class ShortHairedCat : Cat { }

ShortHairedCat shortHairedCat = (ShortHairedCat)new Cat();
```

Is a `Cat` a `ShortHairedCat`? Not necessarily. In this particular case, `new Cat()` is a `Cat` that is not a `ShortHairedCut` so of course you get a runtime exception.

Remember, inheritance models *is a* relationships. It is not necessarily the case that a `Base` *is a* `Derived`, so in general, "downcasting" is dangerous.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out as I was typing the thing. Much thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

You instantiated the object as `StoreCategory`. It's not the same as `XMLStoreCategory`, so you can't cast it that way.

The case where the cast would work is something like this:

```
StoreCategory storecategory = new XMLStoreCategory { Name = "Discount Stores" };
var xmlstorecategory = (XMLStoreCategory) storecategory;
```

That will work, but in your particular case is somewhat useless. Just instantiate `XMLStoreCategory` and you'll be good to go.